# Compare two strings to Date in java

Tags: java, date

I have one date and i have to check whether it was saturday or sunday. Am i proceeding right way ??

```
Calendar gcal = new GregorianCalendar();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
        Date currentDate = gcal.getTime();
        String strDate = dateFormat.format(currentDate);
        if (!"Saturday".equals(strDate)) {
}
```

its working fine. but i cant compare two string like,

```
if (!"Saturday" || "Sunday".equals(strDate)) {}
```

If a date was Saturday or sunday i have to skip the loop....
Thanks in advance...

Comment: You should be using JDK 8 and the java.time package.  GregorianCalendar is Java 1.0 vintage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String.equals() with multiple conditions (and one action on result)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208052/string-equals-with-multiple-conditions-and-one-action-on-result)

Comment: The operands for `!` and `||` and the other logical operators must be `boolean`. You can't just negate a `String`!

Comment: See similar Questions: [How to skip weekends while adding days to LocalDate in Java 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33942544/642706), and [How can I add business days to the current date in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1534804/642706)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to create/format a `Date` object, use `Calendar` methods:

```
Calendar gcal = new GregorianCalendar();

if (gcal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY && gcal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY) {

}
```

Comment: the correct way to check the day of the week +1 for that!

Comment: Gotcha .. Thanks @Florent Bayle

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 3):

> If a date was Saturday or sunday i have to skip the loop.

Then it should be

```
if (!("Saturday".equals(strDate) || "Sunday".equals(strDate)) {

}
```

Comment: Although, this does address the OP's question.. the proper way to check day of week would be to use constants in the GC class.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Is today a Saturday?

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
         .getDayOfWeek()
         .equals( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY )
```

## Details

> Am i proceeding right way ??

No. You are using the troublesome old date-time classes that have been supplanted by the java.time classes.

Another problem is relying implicitly on default time zone. Better to specify your intended time zone explicitly. Time zone determines the date, and date determines the day-of-week, so time zone is crucial.

And another problem is that you are needlessly converting from a `Calendar` to a `Date`. But better to avoid these classes entirely.

## `DayOfWeek`

The [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) defines seven objects, one for each day of the week.

You should be passing these objects around your code rather than a string. Notice in the code below that we do not use strings at all.

Be clear that these [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) objects are *not* strings. They are real objects, offering several methods. Those methods include [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#toString--) that generates a hard-coded String in English, all in uppercase. The method [`getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-) generates the name of the day-of-week automatically localized in various human languages.

Enums in Java are much more powerful and practical than conventionally seen in other languages. See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

> today.toString(): 2017-02-27

Interrogate the `LocalDate` object for its `DayOfWeek`.

```
DayOfWeek dow = today.getDayOfWeek();
```

> dow.toString(): MONDAY

Compare to your target day-of-week.

```
Boolean isTodaySaturday = dow.equals( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY );
```

> isTodaySaturday.toString(): false

Try this [code live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/zVEg8U).

See similar Question: [How to skip weekends while adding days to LocalDate in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33942544/642706)

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
if (!strDate.matches("Saturday|Sunday")) {
}
```

But it is slower.